# Code for viewing the view of the front camera of the iphone

Tags: xcode

Code for viewing the view of the front camera of the iphone? Someone has it? Only the view of the front camera and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the front facing camera like:

> picker.cameraDevice =
>   UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

Check out the UIImagePickerController Class Reference